# MySQL - Group by null value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT date_format(sfo.shipping_arrival_date,"%m.%Y") AS Month,
       date_format(sfo.shipping_arrival_date,"%v") AS Week,
       date_format(sfo.shipping_arrival_date,"%d.%m.%Y") AS Shipping Day,
       CASE
           WHEN sfo.coupon_code IS NOT NULL THEN sfo.coupon_code
           ELSE 'no Code'
       END as Coupon,
       sfo.coupon_rule_name,
       sfo.grand_total AS Endsumme,
       sfo.base_subtotal + sfo.shipping_incl_tax AS Sum_Incl_Shipping,
       sfo.discount_amount,
       count(sfo.entity_id) AS uses
FROM sales_flat_order AS sfo
WHERE sfo.status <> 'canceled'
GROUP BY Coupon
ORDER BY sfo.shipping_arrival_date DESC
```

In sfo.coupon_code are values "NULL" existing, but the query does not list them as "no code" in the result. I want a list of grouped coupon codes and the relevant values.

Does anybody know why I can not find the value "no Code" in my result?

Thanks.

Comment: what is the result? Is it returning the same null values in coupon?

Comment: if you omit the GROUP BY clause, do you get any results with 'no Code' for the coupon_code? you might not have NULL values in this result set.

Comment: I do not have "no Code" in the result set.  When I remove the group by clause I see one line with "no Code" but every other column is null.

Answer (score 0):

My hunch is that you only have `NULL` values for `coupon_code` for the records with `sfo.status = NULL`, which are omitted from your result set.

Try with the following query:

```
SELECT date_format(sfo.shipping_arrival_date,"%m.%Y") AS Month,
       date_format(sfo.shipping_arrival_date,"%v") AS Week,
       date_format(sfo.shipping_arrival_date,"%d.%m.%Y") AS Shipping Day,
       CASE
           WHEN sfo.coupon_code IS NOT NULL THEN sfo.coupon_code
           ELSE 'no Code'
       END as Coupon,
       sfo.coupon_rule_name,
       sfo.grand_total AS Endsumme,
       sfo.base_subtotal + sfo.shipping_incl_tax AS Sum_Incl_Shipping,
       sfo.discount_amount,
       count(sfo.entity_id) AS uses
FROM sales_flat_order AS sfo
WHERE sfo.status <> 'canceled' OR sfo.status IS NULL
GROUP BY Coupon
ORDER BY sfo.shipping_arrival_date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use COALESCE instead of a CASE...

```
...
COALESCE(sfo.coupon_code,'no Code') AS Coupon
...
GROUP BY Coupon
```

... because COALESCE expression is a syntactic shortcut for the CASE expression and as such is much more clear and concise